# Scheduled report did not complete - Update the schedule and change the running user

Tags: user, custom-reports, schedule

I am in the standard 'System Administrator' profile, and this permission has the '**Schedule Future Runs'** permission.

I want to change the running user on a scheduled report from an inactive user to an active user. This report was developed in classic, and is in a custom folder (not in the running user's folder, neither in a public folder). I don't see an option in Classic, neither in Lightning to change the running user.

Can someone please guide, how i can change the running user on the scheduled report.? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, since the report was developed in Classic. I switched to Classic view.

1. Click on the Report Tab , and search the report.
2. Click on the little down arrow as shown in the screen shot and click '**Customize**'

[image]

3. Then click on the play icon on the '**Run Report'** tab as shown in screen shot.

[image]

4. Click on the down arrow as shown in the screen shot and click '**Schedule Future Runs**' as seen in screen shot

[image]

5. Now, select the new running user as seen in screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no option of selecting a running user in scheduling reports, as a system admin, you can simple impersonate/log in as desired user and can schedule the report

Comment: The desired user is Inactive

Comment: From your question, I assume you want to change the running user from Inactive user to Active user. So that means, at present, the user under which this report is running is inactive right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Then in that case, you can impersonate as an active user and can schedule the report.

Comment: How? i am an active user, I am in the System Admin profile, with all permissions. I don't see an option to change the running user to select my name or any other user's name.

Comment: I found it !!!. Will Answer my won question, that way i can post screen shots for some one who may have the same issue.